# Invalid libtool wrapper script when make installing Apache

Tags: configuration

After I configure Apache with standard configurations, after which I do `make` which works. I do `make install` and I get this error:

```
libtool: install: invalid libtool wrapper script `htpasswd '
libtool: install: invalid libtool wrapper ; script `htdigest '
libtool: install: invalid libtool wrapper script` rotatelogs'
libtool: install: invalid libtool wrapper script ` logresolve '
libtool: install: invalid libtool wrapper script `ab'
libtool: install: invalid libtool wrapper script` checkgid '
libtool: install: invalid libtool wrapper script `htdbm ' 
libtool: install: invalid libtool wrapper script` htcacheclean'
libtool: install: invalid libtool wrapper script `httxt2dbm '
```

I was trying to fix a previous error earlier on my Apache related to a .so that could not be found, during runtime, so I might have messed something up and I have no idea what. libtool does show as installed when I do `yum install libtool.`If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it.

Edit: I've been able to install this before, currently the apache I run on my server has htpasswd working as I use it for server auth...

Comment: Any reason to not just use your operating system's apache package?

Comment: It's part of my requirements at University to do this from source

Comment: What system were you told by your professor to compile on?

Comment: We're using CentOs 7.1 Virtual Machines

Answer (score 2):

Agh, I fixed it, doing a simple `make clean` and then re-making it worked.